# jQuery datepicker wont reset disabled days

Tags: jquery, datepicker

jQuery UI Datepicker 1.13.2

I need to reset the disables days based on which selection is picked from a dropdown.

I initialize the datepicker then when "selectChange" is fired, I retrieve a new set of dates and I need these dates to be the new disabled days in the datepicker. This is what I have:

```
selectChange: function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: minDate,
        firstDay: firstDay,
        maxDate: max_date,
        defaultDate: default_date,
        showWeek: show_week,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
           //I have my dates but nothing happens. 
           //This is a sample and it works. all I do is replace the array with the retrieved dates
           var array = ["2023-09-01"];
           var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
           return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
        }
    });

    $('.date').datepicker("refresh");
 }
```

I am getting all of my data correctly. My question isnt how to initialize a datepicker. I'm already doing that. I need to know how to re-initialize a datepicker or how do I reset the days that are disabled in "beforeShowDay" and disable new ones based on dates I retrieve? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-initialize the datepicker after destroying it and disable dates by setting the 'array'.

example :

```
selectChange: function (array) {
    $('.date').datepicker("destroy");

    $('.date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: minDate,
        firstDay: firstDay,
        maxDate: max_date,
        defaultDate: default_date,
        showWeek: show_week,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
           var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
           return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
        }
    });
}
```